# W3C geolocation API's watchPosition isn't working on GPS-equipped laptop when offline

Tags: google-chrome, geolocation, gps, offline

I have a laptop equipped with GPS hardware.  I'm using Chrome version 27.  When I'm offline and using the geolocation API's watchPosition function, it doesn't appear that the GPS is being utilized, as I don't see any position updates.

And yes, the GPS is enabled and functioning well, as I see my laptop is communicating with 7 GPS satellites.

Here are the steps I'm following:

1. With Internet connection **on**, hit this [test page](http://www.thedotproduct.org/experiments/geo/), which utilizes the W3C geolocation API's watchPosition.
2. The test page displays my current position.  As I walk around, my position is updated.
3. Turn **off** Internet connection.
4. As I walk around, my position is never updated.

However, I notice if I follow the same steps using a mobile device (iPhone or Android) with Chrome version 27, I get a different result...my position is updated even when offline.

Why is my position not updated when offline using the GPS-equipped laptop?  Please site your source.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem using a Getac laptop with a gps chip. I extensively tested Chrome 33.0.1750.117, Firefox 27.0.1, IE 11.0.9600.16518 and Opera 20.0 and found that none of them use the local GPS chip. All of them instead call out to either Google or MS's location api. I guess this is because the browser implementors assumed that desktop operating systems like Windows and OSX do not have local GPS chips accessible to them. If they do not have an Internet connection, they cannot get their location.

On iOS and Android, they made a different choice in their browser implementations and do in fact use the local GPS.

The only solution I found for the laptop/desktop use case if you want get results from the local GPS chip is to integrate with it directly using GpsGate, which is a program you install locally. It provides a web server on localhost that will give you the position from the GPS chip. Your js can call it via ajax and integrate it into your application.